# Making Jersey API real-time

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey

I have a Jersey based RESTful API which primarily handles authentication and user management and uses MySQL database. I now need to add chat like features to my web app which probably will scale in the future. I know that there are good toolkits out there to achieving this - FeathersJS, Socket.io, Meteor but they will only force me to use JavaScript and target Node.js as the runtime. I don't want to maintain both Java and Node.js stacks and would like to stick with Jersey (or the Java ecosystem for that matter) as much as I can.

I will be using Angular on the client side.

Is this possible? If yes, what are the different options to help me exploit Jersey to the fullest to also support real-time capabilities?

Comment: Use websockets. You can integrate websockets with Jersey. Check out [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/pavelbucek/websocket-vs-rest) and link to example project at bottom of article. You might also want to look into [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)

Comment: Yes. Thanks Paul for your inputs. Using Atmosphere makes sense.